# Desktop Virtualization in Azure

Tags: windows, azure, lync-2013

Question 1 
Can Azure VDI be created with 
RAM - 16GB
Processor - Intel Core i7 6700 or Intel Core i7 4790K
CPU Speed - 4.2 GHz
Video RAM - 1GB or Higher?

Question 2 
Can we access Skype Video from Azure VDI with WebCam connected to local Desktop
−   WebCam will be connected to TCS Desktop within ODC
−   Developer will connect Azure
−   Launch Skype using O365
Make Video/Audio call

Answer (score 2):

> Can Azure VDI be created with RAM - 16GB Processor - Intel Core i7
>   6700 or Intel Core i7 4790K CPU Speed - 4.2 GHz Video RAM - 1GB or
>   Higher?

No, in Azure, the [VM](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/virtual-machines-windows-sizes) without Video RAM 1GB or Higher.

> Can we access Skype Video from Azure VDI with WebCam connected to
>   local Desktop − WebCam will be connected to TCS Desktop within ODC −
>   Developer will connect Azure − Launch Skype using O365 Make
>   Video/Audio call

Do you mean you want to use Azure VM to access Skype Video, and VM connected to local Desktop, and the local Desktop connect to TCS Desktop with WebCam, then you want the Developer to connect Azure VM?
The Azure VM can be connect with public IP, so it is possible.

Comment: Just checking in to see if the information provided was helpful. Please let me know if you would like further assistance.